# Problem sending PEC on Windows Server 2008R2: The transport failed to connect to the server

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

Sorry for another question about this topic but, after 1 day triyng to solve this (I have read a lot of stackoverflow answer) I have same problem. 
Here this is my legacy code used for sendig a PEC. Everithing works fine until December but from that month PEC service didn't work.

```
Public Class SslMailSender
    Public Shared Function SendEmail(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal MailTo As String, ByVal MailSubject As String, ByVal MailBody As String, ByVal MailFormat As System.Web.Mail.MailFormat, Optional ByVal allegato As String = "", Optional ByVal allegato_2 As String = "") As Boolean
        Try
            Dim sslMail As New System.Web.Mail.MailMessage()
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver", smtps_pec)
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", smtps_pec_porta)
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", "2") 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network)
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1") 'YES
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", Username)
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", Password)
            sslMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", "true")
            sslMail.From = Username
            sslMail.To = MailTo
            sslMail.Subject = MailSubject
            sslMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat
            sslMail.Body = MailBody
            If allegato <> "" Then
                sslMail.Attachments.Add(New MailAttachment(allegato))
            Else

            End If
            If allegato_2 <> "" Then
                sslMail.Attachments.Add(New MailAttachment(allegato_2))
            Else

            End If


            System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = smtps_pec & ":" & smtps_pec_porta
            System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(sslMail)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("D:\Temp\log.txt")
                w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ")
                w.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} ")
                w.WriteLine($"  :{ex.Message}")
                w.WriteLine("-------------------------------")
                w.WriteLine($"  :{ex.InnerException.Message}")
                w.WriteLine("-------------------------------")
                w.WriteLine($"  :{ex.StackTrace}")
            End Using
            Return False
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

smtps_pec = valid pec address
smtps_pec_porta = 465

I always obtain this error:

> The transport failed to connect to the server.
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args)
>   at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message)
>   at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message)

Same code work on my development machine (Windows 10) but didn't work on my production machine (Windows Server 2008R2). I tried disable windows Firewall but result is the same.

Comment: If someone is wondering what PEC is then look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_email

Comment: Are you using ARUBA servers to send that?

Comment: My production server is an ARUBA dedicate server but my smtps_pec value is smtps.sicurezzapostale.it

Comment: Not sure if it is the same problem that I had some time ago, but I was forced to use StartTls and not SSL or TSL otherwise the server refused the connection. I have solved the problem using [MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) instead of that clumsy way required by old NET libraries

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I watch this package. But if I could ask: have you idea why 
did this code stop working suddenly only on my production machine(with development machine I send a PEC with this code one hour ago)? And in order to force StartTls and not SSL I have to change 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl
Thanks?

Comment: To be honest, no I don't know. I am pretty sure that ARUBA mail server worked  last year. I have a webapp used to receive requests to partecipate to a yearly local exhibition and when we restarted the app for this year submissions the mail server was not working anymore. Searching on line gave me the hint to test with StartTls and I got it working again.

Comment: I will try: I'don't know if I could user MailKit (I'm on .net framework 4.0) but I try to introduce StartTls. Sorry for question: I have to enable something on my server or only replace part of code?
thanks for your help